# Absolute Position for pop-up in HTML CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-position

I am trying to get Absolute positioning to work. I have two DIVs that pop up as 'Blurbs' when there is a mouseover event on their respective Labels with text saying "Link".
I want blurbs to pop up 'near' their respective "Links" where the mouseover event occurs (CASE 3 of image). I have put the position of both these `.DV_BlrB` as absolute, and two cases happen.
If I dont specify the top / bottom / left / right properties, then the blurbs pop-up somewhat close to the Labels (CASE 1 of image), but of course, I want to adjust where they are appearing, so I play with the `'Left'`, `'top'` etc properties. but when i do specify e.g. `left: 100;` both the blurbs end up appearing clubbed together on the left side, like in CASE 2 of image. Seems like the positioning properties are not referencing their immediate `.Div_FLEX_COL` divs, but rater some parent div once I specify position numbers.
What could be the problem? Any help much appreciated.

FYI All elements except for `.Main_Big_Div` (anchor) are dynamically generated.

HTML

```
<div class="Main_Big_Div">
    <div class="Div_FLEX_ROW">

        <div class="Div_FLEX_COL">
            text
            elements
            elements
            <label id="lbl1" class="label_l">Link</label>
                <div id="dv_lbl1" class="DV_BlrB">          
                    lorem ipsum
                </div>      
        </div>

        <div class="Div_FLEX_COL">
            text
            elements
            elements
            <label id="lbl2" class="label_l">Link</label>
                <div id="dv_lbl2" class="DV_BlrB">          
                    lorem ipsum
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#Main_Big_Div').on('mouseenter','.label_l', function(e){     
                    var id_BlrB = "#dv_" + $(this).attr('id');                  
                    $(id_BlrB).css('display','block');
                    });

$('#Main_Big_Div').on('mouseleave','.label_l', function(e){     
                    var id_BlrB = "#dv_" + $(this).attr('id');  
                    $(id_BlrB).css('display','none');
                    });
```

CSS

```
.DV_BlrB
{   display: none;
    position: absolute; /* static;  absolute;  */
    left: 10;   /* CASE 2 of picture   */
/*  right: ; */
/*  top: 10; */
/*  bottom: 10; */
    width: 150px;   height: 40px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border: 2px solid #56cfe1;                                  
    background-color: #f8f9fa;                                  
    font-size: 0.7rem; color: #f343a40;
    font: italic;
}

.Div_FLEX_ROW
{flex-direction: row;
justify-content: stretch;
}

.Div_FLEX_COL
{flex-direction: column;
}
```

[image: Appearances]

Comment: Set `position: relative` to the parent of the link. Then you can use top, left etc. to control the position of your 'Blurb'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `left:100px` it is set related to its nearest relative parent. To remove the problem use this:

```
.Div_FLEX_COL{ 
    position: relative;
 }
```